# Detect a variable value change inside a class property C#

Tags: c#, variables, properties, detection

I encounter what looks like a simple flow, yet seem to have open ties.
I am trying to enforce a "commit" upon a variable change inside a class property.

Say I have an interface `IStatusModel` which defines the next property: `Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }`

Where `Status` contains an enum and another class:

```
    public class Status
    {
        public InnerEnum EnumVal { get; set; }
        public SystemPosition SystemPosition { get; set; }
    }
```

Assume I have implemented the interface and covered the case where the `CurrentStatus` changes and requires a "commit" with:

```
        public Status CurrentStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _statusProvider.Get();
            }

            set
            {
                _statusProvider.Commit(value);
            }
        }
```

*(ignore validity checks and others)*

In addition to the above property, the interface class contains 2 functions:

```
void SetInnerEnum(InnerEnum enumVal);
void SetSystemPosition(SystemPosition systemPos);
```

The above 2 functions exist to make sure that in case either the `EnumVal` or the `SystemPosition` are changed, we can call the `_statusProvider.Commit(CurrentStatus);` at the end of these 2 functions.

What I ultimately want is to "detect" a change inside the variables of the `CurrentStatus` property, and always perform: `_statusProvider.Commit(CurrentStatus);`.

I assume I could convert the interface into an abstract and implement the above functions in the base class with just the commit operation, and simply call the base function after the actual inherited functions are executed, but this still requires the implementer of the interface/abstract class to take care of it, which I would prefer to avoid and make it as "seamless" as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: You can either implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Status class, or create another class to wrap it up.

Comment: @user1344783 that is the answer. And it is not by any means "seamless" unfortunately. That used to be the holy grail of UI data binding before the reactive paradigm came along

Comment: @Krumelur, it is seamless for the rest of the code :D. I agree, anyone who had to code view models in C# with INotifyPropertyChanged knows how much boilerplate is needed. But afterwards, it is quite convenient...

Comment: @user1344783 and Krumelur Right, got you, this is what I have assumed, but decided to check nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to make the `Status` class immutable. That way, any change to the status will require a call to the `CurrentStatus` setter, where you can put the logic to commit as needed.